# Magento 2 products showing intermittently on frontend

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, products

Hi I recently migrated my site from magento 1.9 to 2.1.
Everything looked good apart from the products now no longer show on the front end of the site.
However they do show counts in the layered menu on the left and they show up in the admin and when you use the search at the top.

It appears they dont show in the main grid view, however on occasion they do show and then disappear again.
Has anyone else had this issue or know what the problem may be?

I have tried reindexing and clearing the cache multiple times now too.

The website in question can be seen at http://dev.missbella.co.uk

Thanks!

[Screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8WG7.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in Magento 2.1.1 with configurable products. The way it is stored compare to Magento 1.9 is different. Please see this issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5762

Proposed solution is to check and update **catalog_product_relation** table with information which is stored in **catalog_product_super_link** table.